# Eclipse is not showing some of my projects

Tags: eclipse, maven

My problem today is that I have 3 Maven projects imported in eclipse, but the soft is only showing one of them.

About the other two:

- They don't appear in the package explorer view
- They don't appear in the project explorer view, even when I set "Top Level Elements" on "Working Sets".
- When I try to re-import them, eclipse tells me it cannot because they are already imported.

Does anyone have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just deleted my workspace (but not my projects of course) and re-imported everything. I had to reconfigure my entire eclipse but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the projects from the metadata folder and try to import them again.

The metadata of the projects is located in:

yourWorkspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects\

Comment: I tried that but Eclipse was still saying it had projects with the same name already...